# Does java.awt.Desktop need to be used on the EDT?

Tags: java, edt

Looking around I couldn't find a requirement that java.awt.Desktop is required to be used on the EDT, and I couldn't think of a reason why it should be, but I couldn't find anywhere that explicitly says it is fine, so I thought I would ask, since it is an awt class, after all.

Is there anywhere that says officially, one way or the other?

Comment: I would also guess that it should not be on the EDT. For example if you open a Browser you would not want to block the EDT while the URL is being downloaded.

Comment: @camickr, once the brower process started, the EDT would be freed. It would not wait for the URL to load.